# Drupal Module Pages "Statistics" Graphs

Tags: drupal-7

On Drupal module pages such as http://drupal.org/project/views in the right column there are small graphs showing statistics such as "New Issues", "Open Bugs" etc. Are those graphs created with a module and if so what is the module called? That would be perfect for the project i am working on because using "Charts and Graphs" module the graphs are not scaling well

thanks

Lee

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the one that drupal.org uses:
http://drupal.org/project/project_issue